# Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio of multiple Widgets in a Row (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a Row to align two Widgets (VideoControllers) horizontally. Using Expanded and its flex attribute, I can split the available space. **The problem is that the height of the videos always fills up the entire vertical space, thus, the videos get strechted.**

What I want to achieve: [image]

What I have tried:

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio (
                child: VideoPlayer(_leftPlayerController),
                aspectRatio: _leftPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
            ),
            flex: 7, // 70%
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Align (
                child: AspectRatio (
                    child: VideoPlayer(_rightPlayerController),
                    aspectRatio: _rightPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                ),
            ),
            flex: 3, // 30%
        ),
    ],
);
```

Comment: Contain the videos in containers of fixed aspect ratio?

Comment: that would be helpful

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, please wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and give a feedback

```
          LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                return Container(
                  width: constraints.maxWidth,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth*0.7,//70%
                        height: (constraints.maxWidth*0.7)/ratio,
                        child: //your videoplayer,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: constraints.maxWidth*0.3,
                        height: (constraints.maxWidth*0.3)/ratio,//30%
                        child: //another video player,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
```

Comment: you might not require the Container which comes below the Layout builder (kindly check) , Use Layout builder to calculate width and height to layout the UI, Your'e welcome

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with help of Expanded widget. See example:

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    MyItem(Colors.orange),
    MyItem(Colors.blue),
    MyItem(Colors.orange),
    MyItem(Colors.blue),
    MyItem(Colors.orange),
  ],
)
```

Where MyItem:

```
class MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;

  MyItem(this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Expanded(
          child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: color,
        ),
      ));
}
```

Result:
[image]